# libgdx sprite suddenly not rendering, with custom world units

Tags: libgdx

I want to render card sprites using custom units. `1 world unit = 1 card` width, [like is done here](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/a-simple-card-game/)
But the sprite is not rendering. This was working before, but I wonder why its not now. It just renders a blank screen.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;

public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Sprite sprite;
    TextureAtlas atlas;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    float CARDWITH=1f;//chosen as our world unit
    float CARDHEIGHT=108f/76f;
    float MINIMUM_VIEWPORT_SIZE=10f;//our viewport is 10 card widths wide
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        atlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("cardspack.atlas"));
        sprite=atlas.createSprite("c2");
        sprite.setSize(CARDWITH,CARDHEIGHT);//make 1 unit of our world equal to 1 card width.
        cam=new OrthographicCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        if(width>height){
            cam.viewportHeight=MINIMUM_VIEWPORT_SIZE;
            cam.viewportWidth=cam.viewportHeight*(float)width/(float)height;
        }
        else {
            cam.viewportWidth=MINIMUM_VIEWPORT_SIZE;
            cam.viewportHeight=cam.viewportWidth*(float)height/(float)width;
        }
        cam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

[Here is the texture atlas cardspack.atlas](http://pastebin.com/K30eFuhF)
here is a [link to the image of cardspack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTiWc.png)

Answer (score 0):

your card is displayed (at 0, 0 coords) but it's too small:

```
float CARDWITH = 1f;//chosen as our world unit
float CARDHEIGHT = 108f / 76f;
```

if you comment out this line:

```
//sprite.setSize(CARDWITH, CARDHEIGHT);//make 1 unit of our world equal to 1 card width.
```

then you'll see it

Answer (score 0):

Oh, silly me, i wasn't using the camera in render() so the units were not taking effect

```
void render(){
batch.setprojectionmatrix(cam.combined);
..
}
```